# Fiona write crashes

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, fiona

I am trying to write a new shapefile with fiona but after creating the features, i keep getting this output after the program crashes:

```
The program '[6668] python.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I am using:

fiona==1.4.8', 'gdal==1.11.1','pyproj==1.9.3','shapely==1.4.4', 'six==1.8.0'

I tried re-installing gdal but that didnt help.

here is the piece of code that I am using:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import fiona
import fiona.crs
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
import copy

shape = fiona.open("Sample.shp")
original = Proj(shape.crs) # EPSG:4326 in your case
destination = Proj('+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.41666666666666 +lat_2=35.25 +lat_0=34.33333333333334 +lon_0=-86 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs')
with fiona.open('new.shp', 'w', crs=from_epsg(4269), driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', schema = shape.schema.copy()) as output:
for feat in shape: # feat = one polygon of the shapefile
    tempGeometry = feat['geometry']
    out_linearRing = [] 
    for point in feat['geometry']['coordinates'][0]: # LinearRing of the Polygon
         long,lat =  point  # one point of the LinearRing
         x,y = transform(original, destination,long,lat) # transform the point
         out_linearRing.append((x,y)) # add all the points to the new LinearRing
         # transform the resulting LinearRing to  a Polygon and write it
feat['geometry']['coordinates'] = [out_linearRing]
output.write(feat)
```

Comment: In the absence of any code, all I can say is "read the manual." If you want more help than that, you'll have to show your program's code. There's nothing to go on here.

Comment: Not just the code, but the offending shapefile.

Comment: @sgillies Here is the code.

Comment: @JohnBarça : How should i post the shp file? The destination(new file that I want to create) shp file's contents?

Comment: No, the input file. github, dropbox, etc. On what line does it crash?

Comment: You define `dest_crs`and after you use `transform(original, destination,long,lat)` as in the original script [Convert shapely polygon coordinates](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121441/convert-shapely-polygon-coordinates/121444#121444). So what is `destination` ?

Comment: The result of `dest_crs` is a dictionary,  not the same thing as  Proj(init='EPSG:4326') (<pyproj.Proj object at 0x102a15e30>)

Comment: Oh my apologies. The line got deleted while i posted the code and deleted unnecessary comments. I had defined destination, of course.

Comment: On what line does the script crash? I can't reproduce this with Python x64 on Windows with same version of fiona from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: It crashes on output.write(feat). I tried reinstalling the components based on [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100010/writing-shapefile-with-projection-defined-crashes-fiona) but that didnt work either